# Graphic card not detected when installing from flatpack or .deb

Tags: rendering, hardware

[image]hey guys im having a bit of problem, im on pop_os! 20.04 LTS, and the blender from pop shop (both .deb and flatpack) didn't detect my graphic card, strangely, tar xz downloaded from official blender page detect them, any solution?, thanks in advance ,left is from tar xz file the right one is from store

Comment: What GPU are you using? Blender does not support every graphics card.

Comment: @Jonas  my laptop has 4gb gtx 1050 mobile

Comment: @susu flatpack actually quite up to date, its blender 2.83, the pop shop on other hand, they're still in 2.82a

Comment: The snap doesn't work for me on Kubuntu, either.. the direct download is fine

Answer (score 1):

Flatpack, Repositories, SnapInstall versions are created by third parties, not by the blender developers. It is common that there are outdated, missing libraries or dependencies, or other errors depending on the specific OS.

Unless you have a very good reason not to, use the official version from blender.org